# Loop through elements of XML file to see if they include any value within an array?

Tags: ruby, string, include, match, nokogiri

I've read through tons of questions and solutions to determine whether this was already answered elsewhere, but it seems that none of the things I found were exactly what I was trying to get at.

I have an XML document that has hundreds of entries of text, and each entry also lists a URL. Each URL is a string (within  tags), ending with a unique 4-digit number. The XML file is basically formatted like so:

```
<entry>
[other content]
<id>http://www.URL.com/blahblahblah-1234</id>
[other content]
</entry>
```

I want to essentially single out only the URLs that have a particular number at the end, out of a list of numbers. I put all of the numbers in an array, with the values set as strings ( `numbers = ["1234", "8649", etc.]`). I've been using nokogiri for other parts of my script, and when I am only looking for a particular string, I just use `include?`, which works perfectly. However, I'm not sure how to automate this when I have hundreds of strings within the "numbers" array. This is essentially what I logistically need to happen:

```
id = nokodoc.css("id")

id.each { |id|
    hyperlink = id.text
    if hyperlink.include?(numbers)
        puts "yes!"
    else
        puts "no :("
    end
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because `include?` expects a string, whereas I'm passing an entire array. (For instance, if I do `include?(numbers[0])`, it works.) I've tried this with `any?` but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Is there a Ruby method that I'm not aware of, that can tell me whether *any* of the values within an array is present in *any* of the nodes that I'm looping through? Let me know if any of this needs to be clarified—phrasing the proper question is often the hardest part!

**Edit:** As a sidenote, ultimately I'd like to remove all entries that correspond to any links that do *not* end with one of the numbers in the array, i.e.

```
 if hyperlink.include? (any number from the array)
    puts "this one is good"
 else
    id.parent.remove
```

So I would somehow need the final product to remain parsable with nokogiri.

Thank you so much in advance, for any and all insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
numbers = ['1234', '8649', ..]
urls = nokodoc.css('id').map(&:text)
urls = urls.select { |url| numbers.any? { |n| url.include? n } }
```

But it's not efficient. If you know the pattern -- extract the number, and then check if it's in the array. For example, if it's always last 4 digits:

```
numbers = ['1234', '8649', ..]
urls = nokodoc.css('id').map(&:text)
urls = urls.select { |url| numbers.include? url[-4..-1] }
```

**UPDATE**

For the change in the question:

```
numbers = ['1234', '8649', ..]

nodes = nokodoc.css('id')

nodes.each do |node|
  url = node.text

  if numbers.any? { |n| url.include? n }
    puts 'this one is good'
  else
    node.parent.remove
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! Such an elegant solution, and much less complicated than the various things I was trying out. And thank you for also incorporating the last-minute addition to my question! :)